# How do I solve Soko-Trolls 7 puzzle?

Tags: desktop-dungeons

I can't get pass this one. Here's a screenshot of it:

[image: Soko trolls 7]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Move directly forward and attack the troll in front of you.  He will retreat to be above you.
2. Move to the bottom of the formation and attack the bottom troll diagonally so that he moves directly toward the first one you attacked.
3. Move to the spot he was in and attack him again.  He should move to the first target.
4. Return to your starting position.  Attack the first troll, pushing him towards the top of the screen.
5. Follow and attack him again so that he is at the very top of the screen.
6. Follow and attack him yet again.  He will move down and to the right.

[image]

7. Move to the spot that originally contained the first troll, and attack the troll that is just above the center.  He should be forced on to the second target.
8. Move to the top of the screen and attack the first troll again.  He should move down and to the right.

[image]

9. Move to the spot just below the center.  Attack the fourth troll.  He should be forced on to the third target.
10. You're now down to 1 health, so time to drink your two potions!
11. Attack the first troll to push him into the far right space.  Follow and attack again.  Then follow into the far right space and attack him one more time.

[image]

12. Move to the last target, to the left of the troll.  Use PISORF to push him into the wall.
13. Move to the space directly above the troll and attack him.  He will move to the left.
14. Move straight down to where he was, and attack him one last time, pushing him left onto the last target.
15. Attack the center troll to win!

Comment: PISORF pushes into walls, there was my mistake. Thanks!